# Intercepting outgoing deployed Java web application API calls

Tags: java, api, tomcat, war, interceptor

My client has a web application built with Java 7 that deployed in a Tomcat 7 container. This application uses an SMS API with hardcoded config. Is there a way to intercept this API call in order to override the current config and forward it to another SMS API.

I have thought about deploying another war on the same Tomcat container in order to act as an interceptor, since I don't have access to the legacy app code. Is there a better or a cleaner way to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to configure `-Dhttp.proxy` , `-Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore` for the Tomcat to see if it can route the outbound traffic to your proxy such that you can intercept and process these requests at there.

If it does not work, you can implement a Java agent and attach it to your Tomcat 's JVM . The Java agent can intercept the bytecodes of those HTTP outbound calls from your legacy app such that you can transform them. An open source project called [HTTP Toolkit](https://httptoolkit.tech/) already implemented such thing. But it seems that it requires to subscribe if want to to intercept the HTTP requests from JVM.

If you do not want to subscribe , you can refer [this](https://httptoolkit.tech/blog/how-to-intercept-debug-java-http/) for the detail about how to implement that Java agent by yourself.

Comment: You don't need to subscribe - HTTP Toolkit is free for all simple functionality like intercepting, viewing and breakpointing all JVM traffic. Pro is only required for advanced automated rewriting rules, import/export, and so on.